# How to map MySQL JSON column using Dapper

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, json, dapper

I have a table in MySQL database which contains a JSON data type column. Is it possible to retrieve the JSON data stored in that column and map to my c# class using Dapper? Below is a sample JSON about how data is stored in column.

```
[
        {
            "ServerName": "",
            "Priority": 1,
            "FilesystemBasePath": "",
            "IsAvailable": 1,
            "ApplicationDocumentType": ""
        },
        {
            "ServerName": "",
            "Priority": 2,
            "FilesystemBasePath": "",
            "IsAvailable": 1,
            "ApplicationDocumentType": ""
        }
]
```

I want the data to be mapped to a `List<MyObject>` type in C#.

Answer (score 14):

You register an ITypeHandler for `List<MyObject>`, or whatever the property type is.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<MyObject> MyObjects {get; set; }
}

public class JsonTypeHandler: SqlMapper.ITypeHandler
{
   public void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, object value)
   {
       parameter.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
   }

   public object Parse(Type destinationType, object value)
   {
       return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value as string, destinationType);
   }
}

SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(typeof(List<MyObject>),new JsonTypeHandler());
```

After that if you have a column name that maps to a property of type `List<MyObject>` it will be serialized and deserialized properly.